# How could I get the public key generated in the sgx enclave by the function sgx_ecc256_create_key_pair()?

Tags: intel, sgx

I am new with Intel SGX development and I am developing an application on Intel SGX. I want to create a Public/Private key in my enclave.
I used the  function ***sgx_ecc256_create_key_pair*** as mentioned [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-software-guard-extensions-intel-sgx/topic/711087)

How could I get my public key to my application (to the outside of the enclave)?

I want to encrypt data with this public key and send it to the enclave to decrypt it by the private key created in the enclave.

Comment: Can't you use https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx/blob/dc07760567a424521a1f199de4798a649edfa3b7/common/inc/sgx_tcrypto.h#L77 the fields defined in the structure that is returned by the function *sgx_ecc256_create_key_pair* ?